# how to use SURFmex library with Matlab?

Tags: matlab, dll, surf

I want to use SURFmex library with Matlab. I download library from [link](https://github.com/PetterS/surfmex) but don't know where to place this folder and how to include or reference it in Matlab. I am new here and doesn't have so much knowledge of Matlab. Someone please guide me all steps how to add this library and use its function in my code.m file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you need to run `make.m` and make sure to change the directory to your openCV directory. Then you should probably add the lines in `startup.m` to your own matlab startup file.

Comment: Sorry I am new with Matlab so please explain. Where to change the directory to OpenCV? I mean in a file or Matlab main directory? And one more thing what kind of lines need to add in startup.m file?

Comment: If you open the file (in the top directory) `make.m` there is a line that says that it must point to the openCV directory. Change that so that it is correct. Then there is a file called `startup.m` with a few lines to initialize the library. These should be added to your own `startup.m`. If you do not have one or do not know how they work you can find more information on them [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/startup.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compile it yourself, but the easiest way is to go to https://github.com/PetterS/surfmex/releases and unzip the mexw64 folder. Then everything works if you run startup.m (and possibly install Visual Studio 2013 runtime).

If you are not running Windows 64-bit Matlab you will have to compile OpenCV and then compiler SURFmex yourself.

Comment: That is the main problem, I don't have 64-bit Matlab. so can you please explain general steps to compile SURFmex and use it in my file code.m etc. thanks

Comment: The by far easiest solution if you have Windows is to install the 64-bit version of Matlab.

If that is not possible, you’ll have to install OpenCV, install Visual Studio, configure mex to use Visual Studio, and compile the library with the make.m script, which you will have to edit to match your settings. Since you are new to Matlab someone will have to help you.